# Why reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I understand the idea that we can earn a maximum of 200 points of reputation each day. However, I'm not sure why. Can someone explain this in terms of game theory or SE philosophy?

Purely selfishly so, I felt somewhat mistreated when one of my question gained more than a hundred votes in almost one day but my reputation increased 200 and then 200 the next day.

Comment: To make sure you eat, shower and get at least a little sleep.

Comment: I believe it is intended to reduce voting fraud.

Comment: @JoshCrozier: No, that's something else.  See my first comment, above.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap

Comment: @RobertHarvey: but your rep can keep rolling in on a random non-programming question while you eat, shower, and sleep, so that's not really convincing.

Comment: Wait... *this* question *isn't* about profanity? I must have fallen in a well...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: then it makes no sense to award extra rep for accepted answers.

Comment: To give others beside the incumbents with a back catalog of answers a shot at a top spot?

Comment: [The current system is designed to reward continued participation, but not to the point that it creates obsession](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136060) is the stated reason. Though it doesn't seem that effective a mechanism to me for that goal. Perhaps the other point in that answer is more convincing. It helps stop someone getting a load of site priviliges from a single answer.

Comment: Also, if you look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges you can see that the "mortarboard" badge (for hitting the rep cap) has only been awarded 18.5k times. The "Epic" badge (for hitting the rep cap 50 times) has only been awarded 464 times and the "Legendary" badge (for hitting the cap 150 times) has only been awarded 172 times. So it's not like the everybody is hitting the cap all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take a job as a junior developer, earning £25,000 per year.

You work hard, and produce good stuff.

You're promoted to a senior developer, earning £50,000 per year.

You work hard, and produce awesome stuff.

There are no more development roles. You're stuck at £50,000 per year.

Live with it and continue to produce awesome stuff.

Comment: No, no, no. Then you get promoted to management and no longer get to do the thing you a) love and b) are really, really good at.

Comment: @MattBurland: You turn down the role and continue doing the thing you love.

Comment: Sure, but...money £££!

Comment: @MattBurland: Unfortunately the closest equivalent I can think of in this analogy is SO modship, which is an unpaid role ;)

Comment: So, Why reputation cap? (this seems to be a metaphor, but I didn't get it)

Comment: You become so proficient that you can do the work in half the day. You take another job to fill the rest of the day. SE analogy: Try earning 200 on each of several sites.

Comment: @DamianYerrick or on the same site with multiple sock-puppets. Top users 2-10 are Jon Skeet's. Like level resetting on some online games.

Answer (score 9):

Another reason is that rep is tied to privileges on the site. With a rep of 20K you get "Trusted User" and great power. But with great power, as Uncle Ben would tell us, comes great responsibility.

With the rep cap, getting to trusted user would take a *minimum* of 100 days. Without it you could imagine somebody gaming the system to rapidly grab privileges (maybe using sock puppet accounts to vote up their own questions / answers) and then wreaking havoc.

Comment: I guess this is the real reason. It imbues an implicit minimum time limit on rep growth, fixing the fact that Q&A scores alone don't really indicate familiarity with how the site works.

Comment: but gaming the system at this pace would probably imply some detection by the scripts right?

Answer (score 6):

> I felt somewhat mistreated when one of my question gained more than a
>   hundred votes in almost one day but my reputation increased 200 and
>   then 200 the next day.

So do you feel shorted? Why? You have a question that scored 200 on one day & 200 on the next and that is bad why again?

I come here when I am bored & need a distraction. I care about my reputation, but I have also learned that on the Stack Exchange sites reputation has a long tail. Because the goal of the site is providing an environment where long term, well explained questions & answers are rewarded.

I used to be fairly sensitive to reputation until I realized, it’s like anything else in life. I program & do systems administration. I come here in slack time. If one answer scores me 45 reputation points great! And maybe months from now I will get more from someone who tripped across my post.

But without a cap, that would be a wide open door to gaming the system & devaluing the user reputation. Everyone would suddenly have 5,000 rep points in one day. And creating fake surges in reputation points would be easier.

A cap is fair to all. And there are tons of users out there would would love to get 200 reputation points in one day for anything.

Comment: "But without a cap, that would be a wide open door to gaming the system & devaluing the user reputation. Everyone would suddenly have 5,000 rep points in one day. And creating fake surges in reputation points would be easier." Doesn't make any sense to me. Can you please explain how?

Comment: There are more options than a cap of 200, and no cap.

Comment: More options include displaying a log of your reputation